# Ajax too slow to response from server side( shell script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shell

I'm not sure it is my server side problem or javascript/jQuery problem......
My shell script do these things( sequentially):

1. use 'GET' to get parameter from user
2. The parameter such as date and time to change date of server( use `date -s`), Linux based server, and NTP for NTP server configuration
3. rename a file( use `mv filename1 filename2`)
4. store NTP information in config file
5. `killall test.sh`
6. run `test.sh`
7. return message for client side

Now I comment the 4 and 5 mission, but the efficiency is still too slow.
I have try javascript and jQuery :
javascript side:

```
var dthttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      dthttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
      dthttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
try{
      dthttp.open("GET", 'test.ncgi', true);
      dthttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      dthttp.onreadystatechange = onReceivData;
      dthttp.send(some parameter);
}catch(e){

      dthttp.abort();
}
function onReceivData(){
      if(dthttp.readyState==4){
             if(dthttp.status==200){
                   // do something if success
             }
      }
}
```

The response is fast, but I don't know why it doesn't run the script......
However the text from the script is correct......

So I tried jQuery:

```
\$.ajax({
      url: "test.ncgi",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
            // some parameters
      },
      dataType: "json",
      error: function(xhr){
            // if error occured
      },
      success: function(data){
            // if successfully
      }
});
```

When I use jQuery, it does run the script, but it block all the web page, so you can do nothing before the response return from the script.

I prefer to changing my javascript side because the efficiency is good, I just don't know why the script doesn't run.....

Any idea appreciated!

Update:

Thanks for advice of Mr.Manhattan, jQuery can run and doesn't block the web page.

but the poor efficient of response from script is still there......

And the shell script:

```
if [ -f "_test.sh" ]; then
mv _test.sh test.sh
fi
echo -e "$NTP" > configfile
#killall test.sh &
#run test.sh &

varDATE=`date -s "$Date$Hour$Minute.$Second"`
sync
varDATE=`date`
cat << EOF
    {
        "MSG": "Server date/time is set as $varDATE"
    }
EOF
```

Comment: `async: false` ....if you can work with a callback, and can perform other tasks in the mean time, don't use this...

Comment: Well, posting the shell script that doesn't run would be a good start ?

Comment: if you know jquery why don't you use jquery Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for helping for all, I find that the problem is my shell script,

it handle things for too long( the test.sh and get Parameter part).

I'll check that part and hope it can solve the problem.